# Android studios LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

sorry if this question is gonna be very vague, but recently tried to make a game on android studios using LibGDX with guidance from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzBVTPaUUDg&list=PLZm85UZQLd2TPXpUJfDEdWTSgszionbJy

Everything seems to be fine and good as it can be ran on the desktop launcher, however when i tired to launch the game app on an android emulator, the app does not open at all and it instantly states "Application terminated".

To somehow summarise the issue, everything created on libgdx works fine on desktop launcher like that youtuber, but when i need it to run on android emulator, it does not work.

This is the error message:

```
01/27 06:36:30: Launching android
$ adb push C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\TestGame\TGame\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.kyh.game
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.kyh.game"

Success

$ adb shell am start -n "com.kyh.game/com.kyh.game.AndroidLauncher" 
-a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online

Connected to process 2395 on device emulator-5554
I/AndroidInput: sensor listener setup
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1

                  [ 01-26 22:37:34.185  2395: 2424 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f235f7cbd60, tid 2424
W/GL2JNIView: creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
W/GL2JNIView: Returning a GLES 2 context
E/EGL_emulation: tid 2427: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f2362271940, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
I/GL2: all initialized 2
I/AndroidGraphics: OGL renderer: Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600)
I/AndroidGraphics: OGL vendor: Google (Intel)
I/AndroidGraphics: OGL version: OpenGL ES 2.0 (4.3.0 - Build 10.18.14.4029)
I/AndroidGraphics: OGL extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image 
GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 
GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear 
GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture 
GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear     
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot 
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 
E/EGL_emulation: [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
E/EGL_emulation: tid 2424: eglGetConfigAttrib(815): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
E/EGL_emulation: [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
E/EGL_emulation: tid 2424: eglGetConfigAttrib(815): error 0x3004 
(EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)    
I/AndroidGraphics: framebuffer: (5, 6, 5, 0)
I/AndroidGraphics: depthbuffer: (16)
I/AndroidGraphics: stencilbuffer: (0)
I/AndroidGraphics: samples: (0)
I/AndroidGraphics: coverage sampling: (false)
I/AndroidGraphics: Managed meshes/app: { }
I/AndroidGraphics: Managed textures/app: { }
I/AndroidGraphics: Managed cubemap/app: { }
I/AndroidGraphics: Managed shaders/app: { }
I/AndroidGraphics: Managed buffers/app: { }
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Maybe because the emulator doesn't support OpenGL fully. Have you try running on real device?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [OpenGL documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glClear.xhtml),

glClear generates GL_INVALID_VALUE if any bit other than the three defined bits is set in mask.

So, i would double check your glClear sentence.

Comment: Hey! thanks for getting back and posting for more feedbacks on my issue.
 I've contemplated on just holding back on making games using libgdx on android studios for the time being and start focusing on learning how to make some simple apps on android studios instead.
Thank you for your time for reading and sorry I decided to backout when you offered help